# Solr with partial search not working when query is wrapped in quotes containing words separated by space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, lucene, sunspot

Here's my search query:

name_text_partial_all:"hello world"

The field has these words in the index for one document: hello world

Here's my schema definition for this type:

```
<fieldtype class="solr.TextField" name="text_partial_all" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="false" stored="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\d\sa-zA-Z]" replacement=""/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\d\sa-zA-Z]" replacement=""/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="30" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

This is not finding the document. Any clue why?

Comment: Are you searching like this `name_text_partial_all:"hello world"` or like this `text_partial_all:"hello world"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>` will generate ngram tokens which would be at separate positions.
For e.g. Hello World when it goes through the NGramFilterFactory the tokens Hello and World would be at separate positions.
You can check on analysis for the Hello World, the tokens Hello is at position 10 and world is at position 20.
So a query looking for exact phrase `name_text_partial_all:"hello world"` would not work while `name_text_partial_all:"hello world"~9` would work.
You need to either use slop or position filter to maintain the same positions.